# how to create year/month/day structure when uploading files with nodejs multer?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I want to upload the file using multer into folder structure with year/month/day.
Like upload/2021/06/27/filename. How can I do that?

```
//configuring multer storage for images
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'upload/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function using `fs` library functions,

- initialize fs lib

```
const fs = require("fs");
```

- create a method to return date path on the base of input param current date
- ex:

  - input: `new Date()`
  - return: "2021/6/27"

```
function getDatePath(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate();
}
```

- create directory recursive if it does not exist, can handle with try-catch block

```
function getDirPath(dirPath) {
    try {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dirPath)) fs.promises.mkdir(dirPath, { recursive: true });
        return dirPath;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
}
```

- use the above method in destination

```
//configuring multer storage for images
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, getDirPath('upload/' + getDatePath(new Date())));
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, '-') + '-' + file.originalname);
    }
});
```